# extjs 5 - Include only treegrid in the project

Tags: extjs, extjs5, treegrid

I'm struggling with this for a few hours now. Is there a way to include files correspondent to only one component from the extjs 5? I'm only using the treepanel/treegrid and nothing else, so I don't need the 1mb file included in my project. It is possible to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Sencha Cmd to generate and build your application. The resulting minified app.js and App-all.css will contain only required classes and styles.

Comment: I tried these steps http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/extjs/cmd_app.html but it generated a empty extjs application structure and what I need are the files or file to include only the treegrid. I don't know if you understood my question, but if you did, do you have the commands to do what you said?

Comment: I meant it other way round: Create your ExtJS application using Sencha Cmd, make it working and then compile it using Cmd. This concatenates and minifies your application + needed Ext JS classes and creates one app.js file.